# The "special" number $8263$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, decimal-expansion

Prime $8263\equiv 1\pmod {17}$ and $8\cdot 2\cdot 6\cdot 3\equiv -1\pmod {17^2}$.

Are there other odd primes $p$ without digit $0$ such that:

$p\equiv 1\pmod q$ and the product of the digits of $p$ is $\equiv -1\pmod {q^2}$?

with $q$ some other odd prime? In particualar I ask for other solutions for $q=17$.

Comment: slightly different

Comment: @MartinR It has changed to modulo $q^2$ for the product of digits.

Comment: yes infact you are right

Comment: That being said, I would still like the link to [the precious question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173201/prime-8263-again) stay in the comment section.

Comment: What is it with you and $8263$, by the way? You have asked [a lot](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173000/primes-7-and-8263) of [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173036/prime-8263-is-it-the-only-one-with-this-property) about it just in the last few hours.

Comment: @Arthur it is the largest known $p_k$ that divides 2+3+5+7+11+13+...+$p_k$+p${k+1}$

Comment: @homunculus It is also the largest known $p_k$ that divides $8263!$, but I fail to see what is interesting or special about this. Why stop summing at $p_{k+1}$? Why not at $p_k$, or $p_{2k}$, or $p_{p_k}$ for that matter? Also, are you only considering digits in base $10$?

Comment: @homunculus Do you mean $\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}p_j$?

Comment: @J.G. yes it is so

Comment: Some examples (for $q = 17$): $8263, 21863, 42433, 49811, 92821, 118661, 138143, 143243, 182921, 198221, 223381, 224129, 234431, 266221, 331841, 342143, 364141, 381413, 432413, 443123, 461143, 614143, 644131, 655657$

Comment: @Servaes  What did you mean that p divides 8263! ?  If its factorial as by notation, then how can it be largest?

Comment: Related questions; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173263/the-special-number-8263?noredirect=1&lq=1
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173500/magic-properties-of-prime-8263
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173000/primes-7-and-8263

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the next few examples for $q=17$ are 21863, 42433, 49811, 92821, 118661, 138143, 143243, 182921, 198221, 223381...

There are plenty of smaller solutions for some other $q$, mostly with $q=3$ (the first such example is 157) but also a few with $q=5$ or $q=7$; additionally 1873 works for $q=13$ and 3851 for $q=11$.

Comment: and before 8263?

Comment: 8263 is the smallest example, at least for $q=17$.

Comment: For general $q$ there are lots of smaller solutions, will edit.

Comment: do you think that every smallest example for $q\neq 17$ is less than $8263$?

Comment: Of course not, only those I mentioned are. No doubt there are examples for every $q$. The smallest for $q=19$ is 38153, for example.

Comment: the decimal digits in $8263!$ is also 1 mod 17